# Why should my answer be a comment?

Tags: discussion, comment, answers

Can anybody tell me why my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673094/5-conditions-with-a-a-b-b-a-cap-b-c/1673103#1673103) is deleted?  I think none of the reasons listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) is applicable:

- commentary on the question or other answers
- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

There is a note added to the deleted answer:  "your post was converted to a comment", but that is not true. Actually I converted the post in a comment ( the comments are now deleted). The answer is only a partial answer, and it  is more a very, very strong hint than an 100% answer. It is rather short but nevertheless I think it is a good answer. So I don't understand while it is deleted.

I'm not interested in the original question nor in the deleted answer. I am only interested why it should be a comment and not an answer. I had a post on another stackexchange site were I was told that it is wrong to put partial, short  answers in a comment and that one should create an answer. Are there such differences between math.stackexchange.com and dba.stackexcnage.com in definition of what is an answer and what is a comment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your post does not answer the question asked. It is indeed a comment rather than an answer. It was flagged as "not an answer", and a moderator agreed and so the answer was converted to a comment.

Comment: I don't think that it is a [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)  but I think you described what happend,